# $push is not working in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to have a data structure like this -

`collegeName: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    semesters: [
        {
            name : {
                type: String,
                default: null
            },
            professors : [],
            students : []
        }
    ],
    pictureURL: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    time: {
        type : Date,
        default: Date.now
    }`

Thats how I defined my mongoose schema.

But now I am trying to update the semesters array like this -

```
await NewCollege.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            collegeName : college
        },
        {
            $push: {
                "semesters": { name : "college", professors : ["prof A", "prof B"], students : ["Student A", "Student B", "Student C"]},
            }
        },
        {
            new : true
        },
    )
    .then((result) => {
        dataToSendBack = result
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        return h.response(err)
    })
```

But I don't get the desired result when I post from postman, its throwing an error. Please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post the error from postman?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn please check the answer i just posted. It contains the error image.

Comment: If you have server log / application error log it should be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you post the full code?

`collegeName` is a `string` so I think the correct condition is:

```
{collegeName: "college"}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is the postman error. Please have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWTUo.png)